# analytical solution to 2 variable PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wonder whether there is approximate analytical solution to the problem like below:

$$\begin{align}y'&= ay+wz\\
z'&= -wz + b(1-z)\end{align}$$

$a$ and $b$ are constants, w can change across time.

Comment: This doesn't look like a PDE, but a coupled system of ODE.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}y'&= ay+wz\\
z'&= -wz + b(1-z)\end{align}$$
This is a system of two ODE with two unknown functions $y(t)$ and $z(t)$.

It includes a variable parameter, the function $w(t)$. An analytic solution can be derived only if the function $w(t)$ is supposed to be a given function. Of course, the solution will involves $w(t)$.

[image]

Comment: How about the other type of couple ODE? y'=ay+bz, z'=-by+cz+d, a,b,c,d are constants?

Comment: Put z=(y'-ay)/b into z'=-by+cz+d and solve the second order linear ODE for y.